# How to update all previous records from duplicate records in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

in my mysql table, there is a columns that is - id, customer_id, remark, flag.
And table data is like

```
-----------------------
|id | cid| remark|flag|
-----------------------
|1  |5   |Hello  |1   |
|2  |5   |Hell2  |1   |
|3  |5   |Hell3  |0   |
|4  |5   |Hell4  |1   |
|5  |8   |Hell1  |0   |
|6  |8   |Hell3  |1   |
```

In this table i want to update record of **flag** , and condition is, only update all previous record of each cid expects last record.

### Result like this-

```
|id | cid| remark|flag|
-----------------------
|1  |5   |Hello  |0   |
|2  |5   |Hell2  |1   |
|3  |5   |Hell3  |0   |
|4  |5   |Hell4  |1   |
|5  |8   |Hell1  |0   |
|6  |8   |Hell3  |1   |
```

In 2nd table only change all previous records of each customer but latest value i.e. id=3(latest value of cid 5) and id=6(latest value of cid 6) not changed.
Please give me what query i have to run to make this approach.

Comment: This is asking for data inconsistency. Create a view instead, or at least use triggers to manage that column.

Comment: When you say 'expects', do you mean 'except'? Also, I don't consider this data set adequately representative

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question (you need to look at the edit history).

I think you want:

```
select t.*,
       (case when min(id) over (partition by cid) = id
             then 0 else 1
        end) as flag
from t;
```

If you want to update the table, then:

```
update t left join
       (select cid, min(id) as min_id
        from t
        group by cid
       ) tt
       on t.id = tt.min_id
    set flag = (case when tt.cid is null then 1 else 0 end);
```

The `set` can be simplified to:

```
    set flag = (tt.cid is null);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=64ec0b3fecbf124157f8eb5ddacd1e31) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i want to update. This query will update?

Comment: why use null because column data type is int type.

Comment: A left join on an update seems somehow counterintuitive.

Comment: this query working but only 2 record of each cid is changing above 2 records it is not change all previous records

Comment: @IndreshMalviya . . . This answers the question that you originally asked -- and answers it correctly.  I have added a db<>fiddle.  If you have a *new* question, you should ask it as a *new* question.  Editing your question in a way that invalidates answers is not nice behavior.